# How can a genetic algorithm optimize a neural network's weights without knowing the search volume?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I've implemented a genetic algorithm trained neural network with a mutation operator like so:

```py
def mutation(chromosome, mutation_rate):
  for gene in chromosome:
    if random.uniform(0.00, 1.00) <= mutation_rate:
      gene = random.uniform(-1.00, 1.00)
```

And chromosomes are initialized randomly initially:

```py
def make_chromosome(chromosome_length):
  chromosome = []
  for _ in range(chromosome_length):
    chromosome.append(random.uniform(-1.00, 1.00))
  return chromosome
```

When performing crossover, offspring chromosomes can only ever have genes within the interval `[-1, 1]` because parent chromosomes also only have genes in that interval. When an offspring is mutated, it likewise keeps its genes within that interval.

This seems to work for some problems but not others. If a neuron's optimal weights are within `[-1, 1]`, then the genetic algorithm works, but what if a neuron's optimal weights are within a different interval?

For example, if I trained a network using backpropagation with termination condition of classification error below 5%, I can look at the network weights and see values like `-1.49`, `1.98`, `2.01`, etc. My genetic algorithm could never produce those genes because genes are initialized within `[-1, 1]` and crossover and mutation cannot produce genes outside of that range either.

It seems I need to define the search space better, something like so:

```py
# search space boundaries
S_MIN = -1.00
S_MAX = 1.00

# in mutation()
gene = random.uniform(S_MIN, S_MAX)

# in make_chromosome()
chromosome.append(random.uniform(S_MIN, S_MAX))
```

I can then set the search space boundaries based on the problem. But how do I determine the search space? This information isn't known a priori and is found through training the network. But if the training requires the search space be known, I'm then at a standstill.

I could set the search space as arbitrarily large (eg. assuredly larger than necessary), but then the algorithm converges slowly. I need to know at least a ballpark figure of the search space for the genetic algorithm to be efficient.

With backpropagation, the search space isn't known a priori and it doesn't matter, but for GA it does.

Comment: Maybe you should consider a different mutation operator? One that doesn't use any bounds? E.g. `gene = random.gauss(mu=gene, sigma=scale)` (+ possibly decaying `scale` over time). Anyway, if you normalize your data, you can expect the weights to be on the same order of magnitude, i.e. `(-10, 10)` should suffice as bounds.

Comment: @a_guest can you elaborate on data normalization? Is there a relationship between optimal network weights and the magnitude of data attributes?

Comment: For example normalize to zero mean and unit variance. Depending on your network architecture, weights are expected not to diverge too much, but there's no guarantee either. You can start with some boundary values and if you don't reach the desired accuracy you can still widen the boundaries. Anyway there's a reason that neural networks are typically fitted using gradient based optimizer.

Comment: @a_guest your info would do well as an answer, not just a comment. I found using a normally distributed mutation around the chromosome average seemed to work great, doubly so after normalizing the data. For the sets I've tried, network weights almost always end up around `[-3, 3]` but not really for deeper networks. I've added a bounty for more authoritative answers but I'd like to upvote your answer as it did help.

Comment: gator when you start to update the `mu` and `sigma` of the sampling distribution by way of loss you are also approaching the idea of [bayesian neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07710)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a restatement of the core challenge of reinforcement learning with neural networks. You have a loss function that numerically quantifies how good the possible actions are in the current local of the solution space, such that when the action is taken will move you closer/further away from the global optima (the answer). {i.e. gradients w.r.t. loss function}

Before you start you cannot know where exactly the answer lies so you have an exploration policy that you define as part of the algorithm. This drives the exploration of the possible solution space guided by how much improvement certain actions have in moving closer to the answer as defined by the loss function.

At the outset the exploration is very aggressive and makes bold moves so that it can quickly explore the solution space. Then as areas of the solution space present as more promising the exploration becomes less bold in an attempt to converge on the solution.

In your case the exploration policy would vary the mutation size, mutation rate and the cross over of the chromosomes. The mutation size and rate would represent move size within a local and the crossover would represent a dimensional transposition in solution space.

So rather than have max/min you would have a starting position in solution space and assuming uniformly scaled and normalised solution space features a best guess would be any random spot in unit space.

The exploration policy would then select mutation size, rate and cross over to be initially aggressive to explore widely. Selection of subsequent generations would prefer ones that were closer to the answer and with a less aggressive exploration strategy. So the latter generations would tend to be closer to the ‘answer’ and also with a less aggressive exploration strategy and would thus tend to converge.

This article has a more formal review of the concepts.

https://towardsdatascience.com/reinforcement-learning-demystified-exploration-vs-exploitation-in-multi-armed-bandit-setting-be950d2ee9f6

Answer (score 3):

Here's a story.  There was once a presentation, probably of [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4934359/) paper, for genetic algorithms to configure the inputs, outputs, and architecture for indoor flight.  That is, it hooked up stupid sensors to those floating indoor blimps and made them explore rooms while optimizing for straight and level flight.

The "genes" in this case were:

- Choosing two or three input values from a list of responses to standard imaging processing filters (vertical edge detection, low contrast, line detection, etc.)
- Choosing two output connections from a a list of standard voltage profiles for each engine (hard ramp/slow ramp/immediate to 0%, 50%, 100%, -50%, -100%, etc.)
- Choosing connections between nodes in a two level neural network, each layer having only five nodes.  For example, "input 2 attaches to node 3 in layer 1".  Only some fraction (30%?) of connections would be allowed.

So, one DNA consisted of two input nodes, fifty connections, and two output nodes.  A population starts with a hundred random DNA choices, runs the blimps which trains the neural nets selected, calculates the level flight time, and breeds.  By breed, I mean it kills the lowest scoring half and creates mutated copies of the winners.  Success happened.

Now, relating to your problem.

You need to be very clear on what can be your genes.  Some good choices might be:

- Network architecture, as in the above story
- Hyper parameters for knock-out, learning rates, restarts, loss functions, and more.
- Initial weight distributions, actually more parameters, including some for adding occasional wild weights.
- Wild kicks to one parameter or another, meaning picking an axis or two to search with wild values or with fine grain precision.

Also remember that mutation and cross breeding are different.  You should allow  wild mutations sometimes.  A common tactic to to breed about 70% (make a copy, swapping some genes) and mutating about 30% (copy a survivor and make random changes).

As is often with quick advice, I'm guessing what's not said in your description.  If I'm totally off base on what you are doing, pretend its on base; you are 
likely to be the one to solve your problem.

Comment: This seems to be more about optimizing topology and hyperparameter selection rather than using GA to train a network. The paper you link does give some ideas on balancing exploration and exploitation which is completely what I'm after, however, as I find defining exploration and exploitation policies to be the biggest hurdle to using GA to optimize network weights for training.

Answer (score 0):

As per @a_guest's comment, I found best performance using a mutation operator which perturbs a gene around a normal distribution. I did three tests:

- perturbing genes randomly uniform within `[-1.00, 1.00]`
- perturbing genes within a normal distribution around the average of all genes in the chromosome
- perturbing genes within a normal distribution around the gene being mutated

I've labelled the tests #1, #2, #3. This is using the Iris dataset in a 4-3-3 network using ReLU activation function. One run per test wouldn't be significant because it can be lucky or unlucky so this plot is using the average between the thirty best runs from a sample of fifty runs.

[image]

You can see BP-NN gives a nice baseline to compare to.

My uniformly random mutation operator gets trapped in local minima almost immediately because there's no exploration of the search space (as genes can never be outside `[-1, 1]`, i.e. my naive approach I started this question with).

The gaussian operator around the chromosome average works well, reaching an MSE <= 0.1 at the 32nd epoch (compare backprop at the 50th epoch). The gaussian operator around the gene being mutated also works well, reaching the same MSE threshold at the 26th epoch.

I think mutating around the gene average makes a little less sense than mutating around the mutating gene since if you consider were a gene to be mutated twice (once in two generations), there is less exploration. A single gene being mutated doesn't change the gene average much and if a gene were to be mutated a second time, there isn't much added exploration.

If you had a gene average `0.00`, a gene was `0.00`, mutated to `2.00` at the extreme end, the gene average might have changed only a slight amount (eg. `0.10`). The next time mutation comes around, the gene might be `2.00` but the average hasn't moved far from `0.00`. Maybe the second mutation would perturb the gene to `2.05` at the extreme end. Using a gaussian operator around the specific gene instead might see it change to `4.00` on the extreme end.

I think a gaussian mutation operator with `mu = mutating gene` and `sigma = decreasing as MSE decreases` is the best approach. I've tried `sigma = 0.7 + MSE` seems to work great, at least for this data set, because the maximal MSE is around 0.7. The exploratory factor shrinks as MSE approaches 0 meaning more exploration early and more local exploitation later. This also means I don't need to define or even know the search volume.